# How to get log4j output from within a jar file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I can get logs written into a file when I run within a program. But after making program's jar file and running that jar with `ProcessBuilder`, it does generate the file but it does not write anything. Any help is appreciated.

Here is properties file

```
log4j.rootLogger=fatal,CONSOLE,R

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=H://decompilerDirectory//logs/testlog.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=60000KB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=15
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d - %c - %p - %m%n
```

This is how I run the program

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_13\\bin\\javaw.exe", "-jar", "ta.jar", filePath);

Process p = pb.start();
p.waitFor();
```

Comment: Have you set your main class in the jar's manifest file ?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Have you tried using `java.exe` instead of `javaw.exe` ?
Have you tried your command in the command line first and see what happens ?

Comment: Yes. I have main function. The (jar's)program actually decompiles a file first and then logging happens. The jar file successfully decompiles and generates the decompiled file. But it logs are not written.

Comment: It's not about the main method, it's about the main-class. Check the link I gave you. If you want to run a jar file from the command line you need to have it's main-class set in it's manifest file, else, specify the class you'd like to execute it's main function. Ex: `java -jar jar-file-name.jar com.yourcompany.yourclass main-method-arguments-spearated-with-spaces`

Comment: Thanks. I was actually missing main-class as well as .properties file from the jar file. Now it is working fine.

Comment: Congrats. I posted the solution as an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set your [main-class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) in the jar's manifest file ?

It's not about the main method, it's about the main-class. Check the link I gave you. If you want to run a jar file from the command line you need to have it's main-class set in it's manifest file, else, specify the class you'd like to execute it's main function.

```
java -jar jar-file-name.jar com.yourcompany.yourclass main-method-arguments-spearated-with-spaces
```